# c# read each line containing CMD.EXE comand from text file and process it correctly

Tags: c#, file, command

I just need a specific answer here: 
 I am able to create a file containing the command and options I need in the specific format required on each line for example :

```
@"C:\mydosprog\mydosprog.exe" -o=option1 -option2 
@"C:\mydosprog\mydosprog.exe" -o=option1 -option2 
@"C:\mydosprog\mydosprog.exe" -o=option1 -option2 
 ... and more lines
```

Here is the code I am using :

```
var launchmyfile = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\foo\mycommands.txt");
       for (int i = 0; i < inputLines.Length; i++)
       System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(???????);
       //this is where i'm battling and at the ??'s :-)
```

Is there a simple and efficient way of doing this ? (Similar to a dos batch file but in c#)
If so how ?

I would appreciate any tips and tricks and answers

Thank you

Comment: do a google search on `command line parameters or arguments` there are plenty of examples on how to do this when using the `Process.Start` Method [msdn Process.Start Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @MethodMan  .. have already had googled and do know where to place args for a command .. please re-read the question carefully :-) Thanks for the input though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate `inputLines` instead of `launchmyfile`.

However you need to:

- Remove the @ symbol from the file, its meaningless as as the verbatim decorator when its inside a string and not valid in a path for Process.Start
- Keep the quotes, these can be used to distinguish the path from the command line & you will need to break them apart in your program

---

```
// test file
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\TEMP\TEST.TXT", new string[] {
    @"""c:\windows\system32\ping.exe"" -n 3 google.com",
    @"""c:\windows\system32\ping.exe"" -n 3 google.com",
    @"""c:\windows\system32\ping.exe"" -n 3 google.com",
});

var launchmyfile = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\TEMP\TEST.TXT");

for (int i = 0; i < launchmyfile.Length; i++)
{
    // 2nd " breaks the path from the command line
    int commandLinePos = launchmyfile[i].IndexOf("\"", 1);

    // get path
    string executable = launchmyfile[i].Substring(1, commandLinePos - 1);

    // get command line
    string commandLine = launchmyfile[i].Substring(commandLinePos + 2);

    // execute
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(executable, commandLine);
}
```

Comment: @ AlexK Thanks a million for the reply ... but your code doen't seem to work , I get what you're trying to do but I'm still battling. As regards the @ sign , this is used to keep the preserve the command in quotes which does work if a single process is run like this System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("@C:\mydosprog\mydosprog.exe" -o=option1 -option2)

Comment: I can see no use of the @, `@""` in C# syntax is valid, as a shell command line `@c:\xxx` (inside a string) its not.

Comment: @ Alex K :-) thanks for the heads up ..I have edited the main question .. and added a reason for the edit ... For some reason the initial import put the @sign in the wrong position :-) SORRY ..and will test update now. will post update as soon as it's done :-)

Comment: The @ in the file is just an @ character in some text; @"string" is only valid in C# source code files where the compiler will deal with it when you compile your binary, you really don't need it

Comment: K ...wow your code example works like a charm and so smooth for the ping :-) !! I notice I gather it would work for the example I posted too ..Thank you kindly. I Still have an issue though as my actual command/file is in a different location and has more options (the example I posted was the first version!) , I sort of understand how you're managing that but I'm battling to get my head around exanding it to work with more options which is why it probably wasn't working early (I had tried it on the version with longer command options :-( ..see next reply

Comment: Do you think you could possibly extend your answer to match this ? "C:\Program Files\MYtest\MYtest NEW Tool" -n=Win2003A --powerme -dt=quad -dv=volumeabc1 --acceptLicsEula --disableVerifiedone --noSSLLoaded C:\Users\me\Documents\dump\one_system_1.1.img x9://root:P@ssw0rd@192.168.1.151

Comment: OK ass a WRAP .. this works perfectly .. no problems :-) ..again I added a little human fudge factor..(left the mydosprog.exe off the end of the path. Thanks again AlexK ..you ROCK!